Visual Studio 2022: AWS Toolkit broken, won't let me reinstall
I am running Visual Studio 2022 with the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio.  Up until very recently it was working fine, but now when I load VS I see the following error:

If I click Yes (and repeat each time the popup appears), when VS is finished loading, I see this in AWS Explorer:

If I go to the VS Extension Manager, and browse for AWS Toolkit, it shows in the browse list and indicates that it is not installed:

So then, I clicked Install and went through the process of installing the extension and closed VS as instructed.  The VSIX installer appears for a while, and then I see the message below, indicating that the extension is already installed:

After opening VS, I still get the initial "'AWSToolkitPackage' package did not load correctly" popup, and Extension Manager still shows the AWS Toolkit as not being installed.
Has anyone else ever encountered this error?  How do I fix this?

Update: This was ultimately a bug in Visual Studio. Visual Studio 17.11.5 onwards has a command to allow you to reset your extensions. See my new answer dated 10/10/24.
Official Answer from AWS from Issue 441:
We have published a new version (1.54.0.1) to the extension marketplace.
With this release,

we have added some safeguards that should prevent the extension's
startup from failing
we have added more logging to help diagnose if a similar problem
persists
Please share whether or not you have been able to start
using the updated extension. If you had issues installing and
starting version 1.54.0.0 of the extension, and also continue to see
problems with version 1.54.0.1, please try the following:
from a Visual Studio Developer Command prompt, run VSIXInstaller.exe
/u:0B82CB16-0E52-4363-9BC0-61E758689176 to uninstall the extension.
restart your system
ensure that Visual Studio starts up clean (without any extension
start-up issues or messages)
confirm that Visual Studio does not report the AWS Toolkit as
installed in the Extension Manager
try installing the AWS Toolkit


I had help desk (with admin access) reinstall VS, and then was able to upgrade to the latest version of AWS Toolkit by following these instructions.  The VS reinstall was a necessary first step in my case.

This happened to me also.  I wonder if an update to the AWS Toolkit has corrupted it.
You don't need to reinstall VS, just manually remove the extension.
The extensions are stored at
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions
Most extensions are in folders with unhelpful names, so order the list of folders by most recently modified - the AWS Toolkit should be in a folder near the top if you've recently attempted to reinstall it. For me, it was called "cjwfvp5x.jwg".
Open the folder to check it contains AWS Toolkit stuff, and if so, delete it (close VS first).
Once deleted, you should be able to reinstall the Toolkit.
AWS Toolkit is still not showing in Manage Extensions, but it is there under the Extensions menu.
For me, Amazon Q isn't working.  I don't use the Toolkit for anything else.  But this may be enough to fix the Toolkit for what you need it for.
[Edit] See my official answer above

Strange! I ran into the same issue a few hours ago this morning. Tried a number of things but no luck. Ended up reinstalling Visual Studio and that solved the issue.

It hit me, too. I don't have time to reinstall right now..... Thanks Microsoft! What's crazy is it's not anywhere in Manage Extensions. I do remember seeing a popup about Amazon Q or something.

Oh bummer!  I don't have admin access so I need to get our support team to reinstall VS for me.

There are still some improvements/bug-fixes required in AWS Toolkit. Instead install the required templates one at a time using dotnet command line tools.
I installed one of AWS lambda template using below command. it worked, and I can see all AWS templates related to that.
Run the following .NET CLI commands to install these project templates and command line tools.
Installing the .NET project templates
To install the project templates (.NET 8):
dotnet new install Amazon.Lambda.Templates

To install the project templates (.NET 6):
dotnet new --install Amazon.Lambda.Templates

After execution, you will be prompted with variety of templates which got installed. try to create project and search required template, you will find it.
refer below AWS link for more details -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-csharp.html

This was ultimately a bug in Visual Studio.  Visual Studio 17.11.5 onwards has a command to allow you to reset your extensions.  From the bug report at visualstudio.com:

We have introduced a command in this release that should resolve the
issue you’re experiencing. If you continue to face the same problem
after updating or with a fresh installation, please follow the steps
below:

Close all running instances of Visual Studio.
Open the Developer Command Prompt as an Administrator.
Run the following command: devenv /updateconfiguration /resetExtensions
Wait for the command to finish executing.
Restart Visual Studio.



I ran into the same issue with AWS Toolkit with Amazon Q v1.62.0.0.
Solution
While VS2022 was stuck installing the AWS Toolkit, I opened another instance of VS2022 with Run as Admin then approve the UAC Admin Prompt to be privileged.
Once the Admin instance of VS2022 loads it prompts you to install the Toolkit (somehow recognizes it in Admin mode). Then prompts you to close all the Tasks/Processes and finally it works!
Here's the part in the bad log, the good log didn't have this warning:


Signature Details... 17/12/2024 11:55:11 AM -   Extension is signed with a valid signature. 17/12/2024 11:55:11 AM -
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.RequiresAdminRightsException:
You must have administrative privileges to install using the /admin
switch.    at
VSIXInstaller.ProcessRestartInformation.ThrowIfRestartRequired()    at
VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(String vsixPath,
String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData
stateData, IEnumerable1& skuData)    at
VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath,
String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData
stateData, IEnumerable1& skuData)    at
VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.ComputeInstallableExtensions(IStateData
stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported, Boolean isExtensionPack,
IDictionary'2 skuDataMapping, IList`1 installableExtensionsPaths)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at
VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()    at
System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.InnerInvoke()    at
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()


To diagnose problems yourself the logs are named with the date:
 dd_VSIXInstaller_20241217115558_1116c.log

Located in the directory:
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Temp

